# ¿Cómo completar un dataframe con datos de otro?

Tags: python

Me gustaría saber como puedo completar los datos de un `dataframe` con datos de otro `dataframe` (con menos filas ) respetando el Id de la persona.

Aca va el ejemplo

```
Dataframe1= {'idperson': [2,3,2,8,9,20,28,22,99], 'weight' :[222,123,342,763,984,np.nan,212,834,333], 'color':[1,2,3,4,4,6,7,8,9]}
Dataframe1=pd.DataFrame(Dataframe 1)

Dataframe2= {'idperson': [3,5,8,20,28,99,2], 'weight' :[20,33,36,78,55,77,12]}
Dataframe2=pd.DataFrame(Dataframe 2)
```

Como verán hay algunas personas que se repiten . Mi idea es agregar una nueva columna `new_weight`. Donde a cada persona le asigne El `weight` del `dataframe2` (y los no repetidos en `new_weight` dejarlos como `Nan`)

```
Dataframe1_modi= {'idperson': [2,3,2,8,9,20,28,22,99], 'weight' :[222,123,342,763,984,np.nan,212,834,333], 'color':[1,2,3,4,4,6,7,8,9] , 'new_weight' :['12',20,'12',36,'nan',78,55,'nan',77]}
```

Como pueden ver El `ID=5` del `dataframe2` no esta en el 1, así que NO lo pongo en el `dataframe1_mod`.  El `ID=2` del `dataframe1` se repite 2 veces , quiero que queden los dos con su nuevos peso por separado en `New_weight`.

Answer (score 2):

Casi que es un simple [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) del tipo `left join`, veamos:

```
print(pd.merge(Dataframe1, Dataframe2, on='idperson', how='left'))

   idperson  weight_x  color  weight_y
0         2     222.0      1      12.0
1         3     123.0      2      20.0
2         2     342.0      3      12.0
3         8     763.0      4      36.0
4         9     984.0      4       NaN
5        20       NaN      6      78.0
6        28     212.0      7      55.0
7        22     834.0      8       NaN
8        99     333.0      9      77.0
```

Lo que faltaría para ser más exactos es renombrar las columnas

```
Dataframe1_modi = pd.merge(Dataframe1, Dataframe2, on='idperson', how='left')

Dataframe1_modi = Dataframe1_modi.rename(columns={"weight_x": "weight", "weight_y": "new_weight"})
```